# How to install a module on nginx?

Tags: nginx, module, nginx-config

When running nginx -t I get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "subs_filter_types" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my.site.com.conf:285
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

So I need to install the substitution filter module and in the nginx documentation https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/#subs-filter-types
Which says to run these commands:

```
git clone git://github.com/yaoweibin/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module.git
./configure --add-module=/path/to/module
```

The problem is I don't have the configure script anywhere in my nginx installation nor in the 
git repository. I really don't understand.
At the very least I want to know the content of that nginx configure script.

Comment: Do you mean [`sub_filter_types`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter_types)?

Comment: I don't know. Subs (substitution) is what I got. It probably is the same thing.

Comment: Or probably not. I get the same error message using `subs_filter_types` instead of `sub_filter_types`, and my Nginx comes with that module already built in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The instructions you are referring to are for compiled installation.

Assuming you want to add the module *to your existing* NGINX install, below are the generic steps that will get things running.

1. Fetch exactly matching version of NGINX as the one you have installed, from nginx.org onto your system and extract it to, say, `/usr/local/src/nginx`
2. `git clone` NGINX module's source code onto your system, to e.g. `/usr/local/src/nginx-module-foo`
3. `cd /usr/local/src/nginx`. This is where you will find the `configure` script. You will basically configure NGINX with the location of the `config` of specific module in question, thus next step:
4. `./configure --add-dynamic-module=../nginx-module-foo --with-compat`
5. `make`

As a resulf of the compilation you will have module's `.so` file somewhere in `objs` directory of your NGINX sources. You will then copy it over to e.g. `/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/` directory.

To make your existing NGINX load the module, add `load_module modules/foo.so;` at the very top of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

You can decipher the many downsides to the whole compiled approach: one is having compilation software (`gcc`) on a production system, other is having to re-do all those steps any time you upgrade NGINX or the module.

For the reasons mentioned, you might want to search for a packaged install of third-party modules.

For CentOS/RHEL systems, you might want to look at GetPageSpeed repos (subscription-ware, and I'm biased to mention it, because I'm the maintainer. But this is free for CentOS/RHEL 8 at the time of this writing. Installing the module you want, [goes down](https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/nginx-module-substitutions.html) to a couple of commands:

```
yum -y install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-latest.rpm
yum -y install nginx-module-substitutions
```

For Debian-based systems, probably there are alternative PPAs existing for the same.

Comment: What do you mean by fetching my version of nginx? This is my version "nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)" and I have nothing in my /usr/local/src. IN /etcnginx there is a folder called modules-enabled, what is that for then? Thanks for replying.

Comment: Fetching your version of nginx means going to nginx.org website, and downloading .tar.gz file which is the same version as the one you have currently installed. E.g. in your case it is [this archive](http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.14.0.tar.gz). So you'll essentially `wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.14.0.tar.gz` then `tar zxvf ...` then move that to `/usr/local/src/nginx` (the location doesn't have to be exist, I just put that for consistency). Many distros have different conventions for enabling modules once they are compiled/installed. Apparently yours have that `modules-enabled`

Comment: Most likely it has `.conf` files with those same `load_module` directives, for each installed module.

Comment: I figured it out. but now I get this error at the end when the script is ran:
(I do not want to disable it)

Comment: ./configure: error: the HTTP rewrite module requires the PCRE library.
You can either disable the module by using --without-http_rewrite_module
option, or install the PCRE library into the system, or build the PCRE library
statically from the source with nginx by using --with-pcre=<path> option.

Comment: You will, of course, need any dependency libraries for compiling NGINX. You might want to check [this article](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-compile-nginx-from-source-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Ok, I managed to install the module " + ngx_http_subs_filter_module was configured" but when I rung nginx -t again it still says "unknown directive "subs_filter_types" in path/vhost"

Comment: This may mean that you haven't added `load_module modules/..` in `nginx.conf`.

Comment: What file in the module directory should I specify? I have 'config' and 'ngx_http_subs_filter_module.c' for the *.c I get 'invalid ELF header'. Did I add the line correctly? I put it at the beginning outside every bracket. Should I run configure again?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace prefix **subs** with **sub**.

For default nginx 1.10.3 installation (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS)

*nginx -V* should have flag *--with-http_sub_module* to use **sub_*** directives.

Usage example:

```
sub_filter_types   text/html text/css text/xml;
sub_filter         'needle' 'replacement';
sub_filter_once    off;
```

[NGINX documentation link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter_types)