# nginx server_name depending upon client IP address

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

***tl;dr*** can the nginx `server_name` be different depending upon the client connecting IP address?

I have a nginx server that serves HTTP + HTTPS traffic to the local network and the public Internet. I want the `server_name` value to be different for local network clients and public Internet clients.
Local network clients are in the CIDR range `192.168.1.0/24`.

The pseudo-code logic is:

```
if $client_IP in 192.168.1.0/24 then
    server_name = www.local
else
    server_name = www.my-website.com
endif
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can try with [map directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)

Comment: The [`geo`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html#geo) module provides exactly what I want (not to be confused with `geoip`, `geoip2`). Unfortunately, the `geo` module is not available as an _apt_ package for my CPU architecture _armhf_. I could compile it manually, but it is a fair amount of work and has the usual drawbacks of mixing manual compile+intall with apt-managed installs. :-/

Comment: related posts: [_How to install a module on nginx?_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59993747/471376), [_How can i check if $remote_addr IP is NOT in CIDR range in nginx?_](https://serverfault.com/a/743417/116615).